# how to keep some logos in diffrent places using css file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

need place some logos in My index.html file using external css file this is My html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><br></span><b>LARGEST WAREHOUSES</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>


       <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"><br></span><b>GOOD TRACKING SUPPORTS</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>

        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"><br></span><b>LOGISTIC SERVICES</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>

       </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><br></span><b>CUSTOMER SUPPORT</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>
```

I need place My .png logos to the place where span class here instate bootstrap default logoes

```
ex-:  class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">
```

Comment: no any comments

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given.

I would modify (notice the id):

```
<p><span id="img1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><br></span><b>LARGEST WAREHOUSES</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>


       <p><span id="img2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"><br></span><b>GOOD TRACKING SUPPORTS</b></p>
        <h6>Transport provide best theme for lioeiusmod tempor dolor list</h6>
```

They won't all show the same background so they shouldn't have the same dom selectors. If you don't change that you will need to use an nth-child selector.

```
#img1{
    background-image: url("paper.png");
}
```

Generally speaking I wouldn't insert an image via css unless it is a big background. I would guess that you will need to make something in to a "display: inline-block" also otherwise it won't space properly.

Comment: is this .container .col-md-4 #img1{
    background-image: url("paper.png");
}   or #container .col-md-4 #img1{
    background-image: url("paper.png");
}

Comment: "." is for classes, "#" is for id. If you use the id though, you can really do a way with the other selectors that come before it.